# Header file not found when try to build c++ project link to a static library with gradle

Tags: c++, gradle

I want to build c++ project with gradle since I think it could be a good universal build tool for multiple language.I try to add a static library to the project.
Here is the directory structure.

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── libs
│   └── addlib
│       ├── add.hpp
│       └── libadd.a
└── src
    ├── greeter
    │   ├── cpp
    │   │   └── greeter.cpp
    │   └── headers
    │       └── greeter.hpp
    └── main
        └── cpp
            └── greeting.cpp
```

and here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'cpp' 

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            add {
                headers.srcDir "libs/addlib"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile =
                        file("libs/addlib/libadd.a")
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    components {
        greeter(NativeLibrarySpec) {
         } 
        // Let's try using the library
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) { 
            sources {
                cpp.lib library: "greeter" 
            }
        }
    }

    binaries {
        withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
            if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
                cppCompiler.define "DLL_EXPORT" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I execute `./gradlew clean mainExecutable` I got the error

```
> Task :compileMainExecutableMainCpp
/Users/renkai/renkai-lab/building-cpp-libraries/src/main/cpp/greeting.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'add.hpp' file not found
#include "add.hpp"
         ^
1 error generated.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileMainExecutableMainCpp'.
> A build operation failed.
      C++ compiler failed while compiling greeting.cpp.
  See the complete log at: file:///Users/renkai/renkai-lab/building-cpp-libraries/build/tmp/compileMainExecutableMainCpp/output.txt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: If you got a solution, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

I change `build.gradle` to

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            myadd {
                headers.srcDir "libs/addlib"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile =
                        file("libs/addlib/libadd.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    components {
        greeter(NativeLibrarySpec) {
         }
        // Let's try using the library
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp.lib library: "greeter"
                cpp.lib library: "myadd" , linkage: 'static'
            }
        }
    }

    binaries {
        withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
            if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
                cppCompiler.define "DLL_EXPORT"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the build passed.I think `add` might be a reserved key word but gradle doesn't give enough hints.

There is some sample in gradle GitHub repository:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/prebuilt/build.gradle